# Trying to build an array in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I am studying ARM Assembly and i am trying to build an array, but it only print the last word that i write, like the follow example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nzCd.png)

I tried to change the way that i increment index, but i had the same result. Can someone show me what i am doing wrong? Or show me an example?

The code is (forgive me for comments, are in portuguese):

```
.global _start

.equ TAM, 100 
.set end, 0

_start:

    mov R0, #0

Loop:
    cmp R5, #3
    beq done

    ldr R3, =i
    lsl R4, R5, #2
    add R4, R4, R3

    mov     r0, #1                  @ Comando de saida
    ldr     r1, =msg_prod_nome      @ Endereco da mensagem
    ldr     r2, =len_prod_nome      @ Tamanho mensagem a ser escrita
    mov     r7, #4                  @ Sinaliza a saída no console
    svc     0x055

    mov     r0, #0                  @ Comando de entrada
    ldr     r1, =produto_nome       @ Endereco da mensagem
    ldr     r2, =TAM        @ Tamanho maximo a ser lido
    mov     r7, #3                  @ Sinaliza a entrada no console
    svc     #0x55

    str     r1, [R4]

    add R5, R5, #1

    b Loop

done:
    mov R5, #0

readloop:
    cmp R5, #3
    beq readdone
    ldr R3, =i
    lsl R4, R5, #2
    add R4, R4, R3

    mov     r0, #1                  @ Comando de saida      @ Endereco da mensagem
    ldr     r1, [R4]
    ldr     r2, =TAM 
    mov     r7, #4                  @ Sinaliza a saída no console
    svc     0x055

    mov     r0, #1                  @ Comando de saida
    ldr     r1, =quebra_linha   @ Endereco da mensagem
    ldr     r2, =len                @ Tamanho mensagem a ser escrita
    mov     r7, #4                  @ Sinaliza a saída no console
    svc     0x055

    add R5, R5, #1

    b readloop
@ ------------------------------

readdone:
    mov     r0, #0
    mov     r7, #1
    svc     #0x55

i:
    .skip 100

produto_nome:
    .skip TAM

quebra_linha:
    .ascii "\r\n\r"
    len = . - quebra_linha
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Can someone show me what i am doing wrong?

You didn't use debugger: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Programming in assembly without debugger is like trying to assemble a robot blindfolded. It's possible, but it takes much more time (10x to 100x more difficult, no kidding), skill and effort.

I can't find what your "armsim" actually is, and where it has some documentation, so check yourself or ask your SW vendor for documentation + help. But there surely must be some debugger for it, otherwise simply find different ARM simulator/emulator with different tools, because there's little point to learn ARM assembly on hostile platform. The machine code you will learn in other ARM simulator will be mostly same (although the platform specific services like `svc 0x55` may be completely different and maybe some syntax in assembler too, like in PC x86 world there are about 10 different syntaxes for Assembly and sometimes it may be confusing if the source doesn't contain information which flavour of syntax it is using).

---

That was the answer to your question, following are some notes about your code:

```
    cmp R5, #3
```

Unless your platform explicitly specifies state of values after executing your code, using uninitialized registers is bad practice. I didn't check your particular platform, but usually in these kind of learning-simulators the registers are zeroed, but it is not guaranteed, i.e. the simulator creators should have rather put random values into them, to learn people early, how it works in reality.

So this one does compare unknown value in `R5` to 3.

```
    str     r1, [R4]
```

Unless the `svc` does modify value in registers (it probably doesn't, guessing from your output screen, but you should *know*), this will store into memory at address `R4` symbolic value (memory address) `produto_nome`.

So after your first [input] loop is done (which is called `Loop`, contrary to the printing loop, which is called `readloop` ... You should probably consider career in obfuscator business, I see some talent here), the memory content in `.data` section is something like (manually "disassembled" back into source code, but you should try to check in your simulator's debugger, how you can view actual memory content, while single-stepping over one instruction):

```
i:
   .word  produto_nome
   .word  produto_nome
   .word  produto_nome

produto_nome:
   .ascii "your last input", "remains of previous longer inputs"
   .skip <remaining bytes to 100>
     @ ^ = maybe zeroes, if your platform zeroes .data segment

quebra_linha:
   .ascii "\r\n\r"  @ on any decent platform "\n" is enough for newline
     @ (DOS and Windows are different, but those are obsolete and dead)
```

As you can see, there's only the last input in memory as complete one (and even there you don't have any way how to tell where it ends), the previous inputs are overwritten by it (you can try by entering "aaaaa", "bbb", "c" and see what gets out, this will also show you if the newline or zero terminator is part of input or not, if the input is just pure string data, then the result should be "cbbaa".

In assembler you have only physical memory in the chip, so it doesn't grow dynamically like common variables in higher programming languages.

You will have to decide, how do you want your array of strings stored in memory, as there are many options, from:

- the most uncompressed compact form like `"aaaaa\0bbb\0c\0"` which would occupy only 12 bytes, but it's difficult to access "random" index *i*, as you must search whole content from beginning every time, and count the terminating zeroes until you find start of *i*-th string (BTW, you don't need "random" access in your print loop, because you print all values sequentially, so this form is reasonable choice for your current code, but it would be a bit slower for random-access application, but it would use less memory... decisions, decisions... Usually this form is used for things like command line arguments, but there's extra array of pointers provided, pointing at the start of each string, so you get both good performance, and compact memory usage)
- the most simple form, reserving 3x100 bytes, so every input string starts at "array + i*100" address.
- the 3x4 bytes pointer array like you have now, but you must also reserve the space to store input elsewhere, probably again 3x100 bytes like in previous case, and store pointers to this space, not the fixed  `produto_nome` value.

The simplest solution for a beginner is to use N*TAM large memory buffer, and calculate pointers to strings directly as `array_buffer + i * TAM`.

Also if you will modify `TAM` to be 128 instead of 100 (try to use in assembly rather the "rounded" values like 128, the non-rounded values like 100 are in certain situations lot more complex to process for computer ... oh, BTW, if you think "100" is rounded and "128" is not, try to view them in binary, that's how computer sees them...), you can multiply `i` just by shifting it left 7 times (i.e. `lsl R4, R5, #7`) to get the `i*128` value.

So I would modify those shifts in your code, then the memory after label `i:` should be reserved like `.skip TAM*3` (if your assembler is capable to calculate compile-time expressions, otherwise you will have to use `.skip 384`), and make the input reading to target the array memory directly, without additional `produto_nome` buffer, so you don't need to copy the 128 bytes of string to the array buffer after `svc 0x55`.

Also check what exactly the service `mov     r0, #0` does, if it terminates the string with zero or not, and if it returns length somewhere or not. And you should probably print only the inputted length of data, not whole `TAM` buffer (unless the `#1` print service does terminate after zero-terminator or something, but it looks like ordinary `write(...)` service, i.e. it will output to console full buffer, including the junk after the text user did input.